# Why 0x is showing different buyAmount for selling at same price

Tags: 0x

I am working on a project in which I am converting ETH -> DAI and then DAI -> ETH. Since the market is bearish right now, so when I am selling 1 Eth for DAI it's giving me `1573.0360852806744` DAI , but when I re-sell the `1573.0360852806744` DAI for ETH it's giving me `0.998939449793482496` ETH. Why so? It should provide me with same value of ETH I have converted earlier ( 1 ETH ).

If I make the API call in postman and do the same above procedure, I got back the same amount of ETH for which I have converted the DAI. Why so difference in postman request and in my javascript code.

I am using `axios` to make the request.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are swapping with DEXs such as uniswap then they have there fee on it (which is 0.3%) when user swap token for other. Well probably guess this is the thing.

If not could you please specify which DEXs you use and which testnet.

Comment: I am using 0x protocol api . It doesn't allow me to select exchanges, it's just give me best price for the swap. I am using it on Goerli testnet. If you know about any good DEXs fo swap back & forth tokens, please let me know

Comment: ok, well i have also worked on same stuff, i have used uniswap in which i directly interact with contract to swap token, but your charges way less than my. then there is no need. And i look into your 0x protocol and fees are pretty less [link](https://www.cryptofeesaver.com/exchanges/fees/coins/ethereum).

Comment: But your doubt is solved @RishabhRaghwendra or not ??

Comment: I think it's issue with DAI/ETH pair because there is no such issue with DAI/LINK pair

Comment: Are you getting the same out back when you are swapping back of DAI/LINK pair

Comment: ya yesterday I was getting the same amount, more than that actually

Comment: more than ??, i didn't get you, when you swap Dai for link and again swap back for dai are left with the exact token you first swapped

Comment: no on swapping back I get some more dai . For eg I borrowed `1 DAI` after swapping back I got `1.003 DAI`

Comment: As `0x swap` has multiple DEXs it gives you the best price as compare to others, i thin this is the reason you are getting more in return. i saw an api example of `0x swap api` look here https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=LINK&sellToken=DAI&sellAmount=1000000000000000000

Comment: Ya correct, that's how it works

Comment: so now you got it ?